# Building AOSP on Mac Yosemite and XCode

Tags: macos, android-source

So it says [here](https://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html#build-error-on-macos-with-xcode-43) that Building with XCode 4.3 won't work, and 4.2 should be used instead. In Yosemite, XCode 4.3 isn't the newest, but 6 is and you cannot use 4.2 anymore.
The problem seems to be, that "switched the default compiler from gcc to llvm, and llvm rejects code that used to be accepted by gcc".

As I cannot use 4.2, I don't know what else to do. Here is the error I get when typing "make -j1":

```
Install system fs image: out/target/product/generic/system.img
stat: cannot read file system information for ‘%z’: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: File: "out/target/product/generic/system.img"
    ID: 100000600000011 Namelen: *       Type: hfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 31321856   Free: 16227249   Available: 16227249
Inodes: Total: 31321854   Free: 16227249
+
0 : syntax error in expression (error token is ": "out/target/product/generic/system.img"
    ID: 100000600000011 Namelen: *       Type: hfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 31321856   Free: 16227249   Available: 16227249
Inodes: Total: 31321854   Free: 16227249
+
0 ")
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/system.img] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/generic/system.img'
```

I do not understand the error und am therefore not sure if it is about XCode at all.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you run `which stat`, does it point to `/usr/bin/stat`? My guess is that you installed `coreutils` like I did from homebrew and `gstat` is shadowing the one they expect in darwin.

The culprit is probably here:
`build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:stat -f "%z" $(1)`
which is BSD versus GNU style arguments.

Fun times.